# Intellij compilation error: "illegal character' for É sign

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode, utf-8, illegal-characters

I have an Enum class in `Java` that contains the letter `É`:

```
public enum Types {
   RÉSUMÉ
}
```

When trying to build the project, IntelliJ complains on the `É` sign:

```
error: illegal character: '\u2030'
RÉSUMÉ
  ^
```

I'm using Windows 10.

In the past, the same project was compiled and run with no problems on my computer. So it seems like something in the settings was changed that caused this.

There is no option to replace `É` with `E`

Any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT**

- The code used to run with JDK 11 and was upgraded to Java 17. Maybe it has something to do with it. Trying to downgrade the JDK of the project (Settings -> Build -> Gradle -> back to JDK 11) didn't help

Comment: It looks like the character encoding used for the source file doesn't match the encoding passed to the Java compiler, at a guess. Note that U+2030 is the "per mille" sign, nothing like É.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share the error formatted as _code_ to see where the caret (^) points to.

Comment: Make sure encoding is configured correctly in the IDE/compiler settings. See https://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/.

Comment: Works in Java 12 [on Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/waPE5e);

Comment: FYI: U+2030 PER MILLE SIGN (`‰`) https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2030

Comment: Did your problem start when you switched from an earlier version of Java to Java 18 or 19?

Answer (score 2):

## Character set & encoding of Java source code files

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953323/intellij-compilation-error-illegal-character-for-%C3%89-sign/74953918#comment132269205_74953323), likely your source code files were written with a character encoding other than [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Now your compiler is expecting UTF-8, and reading your source code as such.

This problem could occur for either of two reasons:

- Your settings for your compiler or [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) changed
- You changed your JDK from an earlier version of Java to Java 18 or later.

  - Earlier versions of Java by default expect source code to be written in the default character set of the host [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) platform.
  - Java 18+ defaults to UTF-8 across OS platforms for most purposes.

The main clue for this character encoding misreading hypothesis is that code point U+2030 is *not* the [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89) character, nor is it the composition of an uppercase E followed by the accent. No, the code point 2030 in hex (8,240 in decimal) is [PER MILLE SIGN](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2030): `‰`.

### Java 18+ defaults to UTF-8

See [*JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400). To quote:

> If source files were saved with a non-UTF-8 encoding and compiled with an earlier JDK, then recompiling on JDK 18 or later may cause problems. For example, if a non-UTF-8 source file has string literals that contain non-ASCII characters, then those literals may be misinterpreted by javac in JDK 18 or later unless -encoding is used.

You can easily verify if this new default is the source of your problem.  **Go back to your old project, and specify UTF-8 for compiling.** Again, quoting [the JEP](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400):

> Prior to compiling on a JDK where UTF-8 is the default charset, developers are strongly encouraged to check for charset issues by compiling with `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...` on their current JDK (8-17).